# Parse/Scrape column from table using MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Tags: html, xml, vba, parsing

I wrote this piece of code that scrapes the whole table from the webpage in the URL variable. I would like to only scrape/parse the column by the name

> "Extrapolated Vol".

My html/xml is not strong, so a solution along with an explanation would be appreciated!

https://services.tcpl.ca/cor/public/gdsr/GdsrNGTLImperial20151122.htm

Thanks

```
Sub ExtractAlbertaAIL()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim URL As String
Dim Request As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim tr As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim td As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement

Dim RowNumber As Integer
Dim ColNumber As Integer

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Gas Day Summary").Range("A5:H10000") = ""

Set Request = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
If Request Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "For some reason I wasn't able to make a MSXML2.XMLHTTP object"
  Exit Sub
End If


URL = "https://services.tcpl.ca/cor/public/gdsr/GdsrNGTLImperial20151122.htm"
With Request
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send

    Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With



RowNumber = 1
For Each tr In doc.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(2).getElementsByTagName("tr")
   ColNumber = 1
    For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
        Worksheets("Gas Day Summary").Cells(RowNumber, ColNumber) = td.innerText
        ColNumber = ColNumber + 1
    Next td
    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
Next tr


 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
Sub ExtractAlbertaAIL()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim URL As String
Dim Request As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim tr As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim td As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim VOLUME_SUMMARY_FOUND As Boolean
VOLUME_SUMMARY_FOUND = False

Dim RowNumber As Integer
Dim ColNumber As Integer

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Gas Day Summary").Range("A5:H10000") = ""

Set Request = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
If Request Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "For some reason I wasn't able to make a MSXML2.XMLHTTP object"
  Exit Sub
End If


URL = "https://services.tcpl.ca/cor/public/gdsr/GdsrNGTLImperial20151122.htm"
With Request
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send

    Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With



RowNumber = 1
For Each tr In doc.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(2).getElementsByTagName("tr")

   If tr.Cells(0).innerText = "VOLUME SUMMARY" Then
      VOLUME_SUMMARY_FOUND = True
   End If
   If VOLUME_SUMMARY_FOUND = True Then
       Worksheets("Gas Day Summary").Cells(RowNumber, 1) = tr.Cells(0).innerText
       Worksheets("Gas Day Summary").Cells(RowNumber, 2) = tr.Cells(2).innerText
       RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
   End If
Next tr


 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
​
```